# How to use HikariCP with jdk1.7 to get the best result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I have read a lot about `hikariCP` and how it is ["the fastest connection pool"](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) and there is no deadlock reported with it. But when I compared it with `tomcat-jdbc` I get almost the same response times for both (if not `tomcat-jdbc` is faster). Further more I got an Exception when using `hikariCP`, stack trace can be found below. I feel that I did not configure the connection pool correctly.
**note**: my application should accept up to 70 transactions per second.
I am using:

`HikariCP-1.4`

`jdk 1.7`

`Spring Framework 3.2`

`Hibernate 4` 
and this is my HikariCP configuration:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
      <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
      <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="7"/>
      <property name="idleTimeout" value="9000"/>
      <property name="connectionTimeout" value="120000"/>
      <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${app.jdbc.url}"/>
      <property name="username" value="${app.jdbc.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${app.jdbc.password}"/>
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
</bean>
<!-- HikariCP configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

the stak trace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:514)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.ebs.commons.webServices.CommonWebService.processRequest(CommonWebService.java:80)
at com.myApplication.processRequest(AnotherClass.java:70)
at someClass(AnotherClass.java:113)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1396)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:473)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timeout after 120012ms of waiting for a connection.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:208)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:91)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
... 47 more
```

Comment: Not only the datasource is a factor in speed also how you manage transactions, have hibernate configured, which database do you use. For starters I would upgrade to a more recent version of Hikari and use the preferred way of configuring (that is without a Jdbc URL and driverclassname). And I strongly suggest a read of the HikariCP wiki which has hints and tips on how to configure it (the section about pool sizing is also an interesting read!).

Comment: 70 tranactions per second is not that many, and any pool should be  able to handle that. Remember that the benchmark in the HikariCP doc only measures the time taken by the pool to give you connections and get them back. And that time is negligible compared to the time it takes to **use** the connection: execute SQL queries, analyze the results, etc. Using a different pool won't magically make that code faster.

Comment: The latest version of HikariCP is 2.2.5.  Please read the project page docs carefully for configuration.   If you are using Java 7, you'll need the HikariCP-java6 dependency, the HikariCP dependency is Java 8+.

Comment: @brettw now I switched to HikariCP-java6-2.2.5 and set the `maximumPoolSize` with 70 and `minimumIdle` with 7 but still not faster and also I got a " `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException`: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection "

Comment: @AhmedWahbi one reason tomcat-jdbc is faster "out-of-the-box" is that many safety features are disabled, such as ``rollbackOnReturn`` and ``testOnBorrow``, and does not track unclosed Statements.  HikariCP always takes the *most reliable* path, and I think if you configure tomcat-jdbc equivalently, you will find it to be slower.  Regarding your new exception, please update your original question with a full stacktrace.  Many people are using HikariCP, Spring, and Hibernate 4 successfully.

Comment: http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/ says same artefact used for Java 7 and 8 and a different one for Java 6.